# Oracle SQL substrings on three character pattern

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to find fisrt, second and third substring from string like `"One - Two-Two- Three-Three"` by splitting them only by `" - "` (with first and last characters being spaces).

I can split them by `"-"`, like:

```
regexp_substr(teenimi, '[^-]+', 1, 1 ) as a,
regexp_substr(teenimi, '[^-]+', 1, 2 ) as b,
regexp_substr(teenimi, '[^-]+', 1, 3 ) as c
```

which gives me result like: `One // Two // Two`, but I need `One // Two-Two // Three-Three`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
[^- ]+(-[^- ]+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tvagRB/1)

It will match

- `[^- ]+` - 1 or more chars other than `-` and space
- `(-[^- ]+)*`  - zero or more sequences of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[^- ]+` - see above.

Basically, it will match `-` that has no space on either side and non-whitespace characters.